# How to bypass scanning WhatsApp QR

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, qr-code

I want to send my girlfriend a text msg that says "good morning beautiful" in 8 in the morning.

The problem is that I like to sleep in and wake up around 9 now I created a JavaScript Puppeteer application that will send the msgs for me the problem is that I need to scan a QR code and I wonder if there is any way I can scan the code once get the data put it in a database and just use it for future times?

Thank you very much for your time.

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

async function scrape(url) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);
    await page.waitForSelector("[title='my_love']");
    const target = await page.$("[title='my_love']");
    await target.click();
    const inp = await page.$("#main > footer > div._2lSWV._3cjY2.copyable-area > div > span:nth-child(2) > div > div._1VZX7 > div._3Uu1_ > div > div.to2l77zo.gfz4du6o.ag5g9lrv.bze30y65.kao4egtt > p");
    await inp.type("Good Morning Beautiful");
    await page.keyboard.press("Enter");

}

scrape("https://web.whatsapp.com/");
```

Answer (score 1):

The login process of whatsapp web cannot be bypassed and it's a good thing. What you can do to not have to login everytime is to have a static user data directory (profile) so that puppeteer will not open a new session but open a exiting session where login won't be needed.

Just pass a path where profile can be stored. Then run the code, it will ask you to scan the QR code and login. Once you have done the login, you can simply close your program. Now if you run the program again, it won't ask you for login.

```js
await puppeteer.launch({
  userDataDir: './myUserDataDir',
})
```

Here is your updated snippet

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

async function scrape(url) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, userDataDir: './myUserDataDir' });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);
    await page.waitForSelector("[title='my_love']");
    const target = await page.$("[title='my_love']");
    await target.click();
    const inp = await page.$("#main > footer > div._2lSWV._3cjY2.copyable-area > div > span:nth-child(2) > div > div._1VZX7 > div._3Uu1_ > div > div.to2l77zo.gfz4du6o.ag5g9lrv.bze30y65.kao4egtt > p");
    await inp.type("Good Morning Beautiful");
    await page.keyboard.press("Enter");

}

scrape("https://web.whatsapp.com/");
```

Comment: but when chromium is exited that is gone i have to restart the application and all the automation part goes away

Comment: Even when using `userDataDir`? That should persist the session.

Comment: @DanielRaviv You have login once and then it will persist the session, I have updated my answer.